# quasi-totalité ou quasi totalité

Tags: orthographe

Doit-on dire "quasi totalité" ou "quasi-totalité" (de quelque chose) ? Sur Google je vois que le second est plus présent mais je ne suis pas certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tous les termes obtenus à partir de l'élément formant « quasi- » doivent comprendre le tiret ou être soudés.

> ([Tlfi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quasi-))  **quasi-**
> **Prononc. et Orth.**: [kazi-]. Gén. trait d'union devant un subst. avec lequel quasi forme un comp.: quasi-contrat, quasi-délit, mais parfois aussi soudure, devant cons.: quasifission, quasi-fission et même devant voy.: quasiatome (sans chute de i, ce qui peut poser un problème de prononc.), quasi-atome (supra A 1 c phys. des particules, phys. nucl.). V. aussi quasar, forme soudée (avec chute de i) à partir de quasi-stellar. Soudure fréq. devant un adj.: quasipériodique, quasi-stationnaire ou quasistationnaire, quasistatique ou quasi-statique (supra B). Trait d'union devant un adv.: quasi-matériellement (supra C). Prop. Catach.-Golf. Orth. Lexicogr. Mots comp. 1981, p. 202: soudure ou tolérance pour le trait d'union dans tous les cas. Bbg. Blochw.-Runk. 1971, pp. 89-90. − Brunet (E.). Le Vocab. fr. de 1789 à nos jours d'après les données du TLF. Genève-Paris, 1981, pp. 615-619; p. 647, 680. − Darm. 1877, p. 228. − Quem. DDL t. 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 25, 29 (comp.).

Selon le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quasi-totalit%C3%A9) il faut un trait d'union.

La forme avec un trait d'union se trouve dans les pages suivantes, où on trouve aussi la forme en deux mots, mais bien moins souvent.

**quasi-totalité**, (quasi totalité) : [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quasi%20totalit%C3%A9%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quasi+totalit%C3%A9%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=-zWeYvemLIiNlwTv3YSwCw&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi3kOHZqZn4AhWIxoUKHe8uAbYQ8tMDegQIARBD&biw=962&bih=999&dpr=1), [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quasi+totalit%C3%A9%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=GDaeYt2uCKKNlwTglo2QBg&start=200&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjdmqfnqZn4AhWixoUKHWBLA2I4ZBDy0wN6BAgBEEU&biw=962&bih=999&dpr=1), [4](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quasi+totalit%C3%A9%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=KDaeYv2DN5Hga9GekNgD&start=300&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj9t6bvqZn4AhUR8BoKHVEPBDs4yAEQ8tMDegQIARBH&biw=970&bih=999&dpr=1)

Il y a donc deux choix possibles, mais on peut préférer s'en tenir au dictionnaire (quasi-totalité).

Comment: *« Quasitotalité » est aussi courant que « quasi-totalité ».* Tu es sûr ? Je ne me souviens pas avoir jamais lu *quasitotalité* en un mot.

Comment: @jlliagre Il n'y a qu'à vérifier les trois pages pour s'en apercevoir ; c'est un nouvel usage (20 dernières années).

Comment: La forme *quasitotalité* est environ **dix fois moins** courante d'après Google Ngram, quelle que soit la période.

Comment: @jlliagre La somme sur toutes les pages (sans compter les répétitions) est de 259 pour « quasitotalité » et de 196 pour « quasi-totalité ». C'est **approximativement égal** ; je ne vois pas d'où sort ce rapport de 1 sur 10.

Comment: Je sors ce rapport des chiffres remontés par Google. Depuis l'an 2000, on a une fréquence de 33 par million pour *quasitotalité* contre 366 par million pour *quasi-totalité*. Tu penses vraiment que *quasi-totalité* n'apparaîtrait que 196 fois dans les trois millions de documents présents dans la base de Google Books ?

Comment: @jlliagre Je me base sur les données que me fournit Les Livres Google ; si selon deux systèmes de production de données il y a des contradictions, je ne peux pas être celui qui est à blamer ; que Google fasse en sorte que ses diverses recherches  soient non contradictoires.

Comment: Je viens de regarder les premiers livres retournés par Google Books pour une recherche sur *quasitotalité* en un mot, et ce sont **tous** de faux positifs. Il ne faut jamais faire une confiance aveugle aux outils de Google. Tous, y compris les NGrams, demandent un minimum de vérification avant de considérer pouvoir en tirer des enseignements.

Comment: @jlliagre Il est vrai qu'il y a des faux positifs, mais ils sont  très loin de constituer la totalité des occurrences. Sur les **36** premiers livres de la réf. «  quasitotalité 1 »  je trouve **22** cas corrects et seulement **12** faux positifs (il y en a deux qui sont douteux (tiret en fin de ligne, par exemple)).  Il n'y aurait pas plus d'un tiers de faux positifs dans l'ensemble.

Comment: J'aimerais que tu nous donnes le nom vers un livre qui contient *quasitotalité*. Je viens de vérifier les vingt premiers retournés par ton premier lien et **aucun** ne contient ce mot. Soit il y a un tiret, soit l'aperçu n'est pas disponible.

Comment: @jlliagre Je place le résultat de cette petite recherche dans mas réponse.

Comment: Le premier lien contient *quasi-totalité*. Ce n'est pas ce que je te demande.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai pu vérifier un livre au moyen d'une autre source et cela montre que ce que donne Google n'est pas fiable https://imgur.com/jpgD4NR  https://www.google.fr/books/edition/%C3%80_la_d%C3%A9couverte_de_Rouen/VoT4DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quasitotalit%C3%A9%22&pg=PT14&printsec=frontcover. Donc ne pas tenir compte de la recherche.

Answer (score 5):

Si on suit les deux premiers liens que me renvoie mon moteur de recherche, je vois :

– Article *quasi* [dans la BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3577) :

> *Quasi* est aussi fréquemment utilisé comme élément dans la formation de substantifs, entre autres dans le domaine du droit. Les composés formés avec *quasi* et un nom prennent toujours un trait d’union. Au pluriel, seul le second élément varie en nombre au besoin.

– Article *quasi*  dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quasi-) :

> Devant un nom, c’est un préfixe ; il s’accole à son radical avec un trait d’union (*de la quasi-monnaie*).

*La Grande grammaire du français* indique que le préfixe **quasi** requiert un trait d'union s'il se combine avec une base nominale (ce qui est donc le cas ici), exemple donné : *un quasi-synonyme*.

Comment: Comme la réponse est simple ! :)